# How to make this simple view with swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to do this view with swiftui but i am stuck.
[image]

I want the text("Mes évènements") to be centered and I want it to take all the place it can.
The two horizontal line should only take the place left.

I tried with HStack but I couldn't make it work as i would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Here is a possible solution.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        VStack{
        OrangeLine()
        }
        Text("Mes évènements")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
        VStack{
        OrangeLine()
        }
    }
}
}

struct OrangeLine: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.orange)
            .frame(height: 2)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thanks you !